# Assign value from another file sh

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have two file sh. a.sh b.sh

In `a.sh` I have something like this:

```
a=10
sh b.sh $a

echo $a
```

In `b.sh` I have

```
a=$1
if (( 1 > 2 ));
then
   a=20
else
   a=$1
fi
```

I want to assign `$a` in `a.sh` after check condition in `b.sh`.
I try with export but without lucky.

Comment: Have you tried sourcing `b.sh` from within `a.sh`? Like, `. ./b.sh $a` instead of `sh b.sh $a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this-

a.sh

```sh
a=10
a=$(sh b.sh $a)
echo "From b.sh in a.sh a=$a"
```

b.sh

```sh
x=$1
>&2 echo "Got x = $x in b.sh"
if ((2>1)); then
    echo 20;
fi
```

Execution -

```sh
sh a.sh
```

Output

```sh
Got x = 10 in b.sh ## writing to error stream just for display purpose
From b.sh in a.sh a=20
```

Answer (score 0):

If i not wrong you can try like below way.

second.sh :

```
var = 3
echo"$var"
```

main.sh:

```
var = $(./second.sh args...)
```

Comment: better check your syntax at shellcheck.net